# Git ignoring my .gitignore on a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, gitignore

I'm having some deployment problems, due to Rails' `tmp/cache/assets` folder and git not ignoring `tmp/*` or `tmp/`. My entire `.gitignore` is:

```
*.rbc
*.sassc
.sass-cache
capybara-*.html
.rspec
/.bundle
/vendor/bundle
/log/*
/tmp/*
/db/*.sqlite3
/public/system/*
/coverage/
/spec/tmp/*
**.orig
rerun.txt
pickle-email-*.html
```

It's taken from GitHub [gitignore repo](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Rails.gitignore). What can I do to fix it? I get tons of errors due to local changes (in the `tmp/` folder) on my server, such as `error: Your local changes to 'tmp/cache/assets/D32/A10/sprockets%2F13fe41fee1fe35b49d145bcc06610705' would be overwritten by merge.  Aborting.`, so I can't deploy on my dev machine :(

Comment: Can you confirm that the files in the folder are not staged already? If they are you might have to unstage them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you add the .gitignore after starting the project? If `tmp/cache/assets/whatever` already existed before you added the .gitignore, it'll still be in the repo.

1. Try a `git rm -r tmp && git commit` to remove the whole `tmp` directory from the repo.
2. Try deploying at this point to see if deployment works from a known-good state. If it still doesn't work, you know there is some other issue.
3. If everything works, new changes to `tmp` should no longer be picked up.

ALso, as @thenetimp points out, your current .gitignore will only ignore `/tmp`, but not `something/tmp`. I'm not sure if that's your intention or not.

Answer (score 5):

remove the forward slash in front of `/tmp/`  it should be `tmp/`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a sample .gitignore file at: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Rails.gitignore

I also found a good article at http://www.wrel.de/gitignore-und-was-kommt-rein/ (German)